# Calling RPG Programs with Local Data Area from C#

Tags: c#, ibm-midrange, rpg

So we are working with RPG Programs from C# we are using the cwbx.dll in order to access a variety of programs and can execute and get results. [Like this example](http://techmantium.com/calling-ibm-iseries-rpg-programs-api-calls/)

However we have a program which requires that we store parameters in the LDA at specific locations.

Any ideas on how we can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a CL program which you could call with parameters.  The CL could load the LDA from the parameter values, then call the RPG program.

Comment: I agree this would work, so have an up vote for that. I'm going to give it till Wednesday to see if someone comes up with a more direct approach?